# Cakephp Blog Tutorial - Controller $id

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I need some help in the blog tutorial of cakephp 2.0 in the PostsController part

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html

I can't understand where the `$id` came from in the parameter it is defined as `$id = null` so my comprehension is `$id` should be null but it's not null

```
public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }

    $post = $this->Post->findById($id);
    if (!$post) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }
    $this->set('post', $post);
}
```

I know that the real value of `$id` came from the url, in this case `cakephp/posts/view/$id` but I want to know how that `$id` from the url got through the `PostsController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dispatcher takes parameters from the URL and passes them as arguments to your controller actions so you can do things with them, i.e. look up a blog post via an ID specified in the URL.

The default value is `null` in case you request a URL like **http://example.com/posts/view/**. You didn’t specify an ID, so that would be a `null` value and you can throw a 404 error in your controller action:

```
<?php
class PostsController extends AppController {

    public function view($id = null) {
        if (is_null($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }

        $post = $this->Post->findById($id);

        $this->set('post', $post);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that it is better to either do the if statement after your `$post = $this->Post->findByid($id);`, and check `if (empty($post))`, or change `is_null($id)` to `!$this->Post->exists($id)`. You can have a non-null ID that is an invalid post, requiring a `NotFoundException`

Comment: Indeed. I normally use the `if (!$this->ModelName->exists($id))` approach in my own CakePHP applications. The above was just written off-the-cuff as an example.